# Flutter deeplinking not working with http or https as scheme

Tags: flutter, deep-linking

I have added 2 intent-filters:

```
        <!-- Deep linking https-->
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp.myserver.de"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Deep linking otherName-->
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myAppName" android:host="myapp.myserver.de"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

I have create 2 QR-Codes with the different schemes
Calling myAppName://myapp.myserver.de/deeplinkPage - is working as expected and opens the app
Calling https://myapp.myserver.de/deeplinkPage - opens the website

What is going wrong here?

https://myapp.myserver.de/.well-known/assetlinks.json is available
I did everything as described here https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links